# Saving lists of variable length to HDF5 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, large-files, large-data

I'm pretty new to pandas, so please apologize if my questions are trivial.

I want to save a pandas data frame to hdf5 that contains a list of lists of variable length as a column. My goal is to write and read in this data frame in chuncks later on. This seems to be only possible if I store the data frame in table format.
However if I save my data frame in table format I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [pdf] because its data contents are [mixed] object dtype
```

In the following I show a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID'] = [el for el in np.arange(100)]
df['pdf'] = [np.arange(i) for i in df['ID']]
df.to_hdf('test_format_table.h5','df', format='table')
```

If I save the data frame with format = 'fixed' everything will work, however I want to save in table format.

Is it possible to easily resolve this issue?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Markus

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this problem in an odd way. Pandas and HDF5 work well when you have tidy data.

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   ID                          pdf
0   0                           []
1   1                          [0]
2   2                       [0, 1]
3   3                    [0, 1, 2]
4   4                 [0, 1, 2, 3]
5   5              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
6   6           [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
7   7        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
8   8     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
9   9  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

explode the list to columns

```
In [33]: df2 = pd.concat([df.ID, df.pdf.apply(Series)], axis=1)

In [34]: df2
Out[34]: 
   ID    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
0   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   1  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   2  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   3  0.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   5  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   6  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   7  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN
8   8  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN
9   9  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

rename to make the names clear

```
In [35]: df2.columns = ['ID'] + [ 'C%s' % c for c in df2.columns[1:] ]

In [36]: df2
Out[36]: 
   ID   C0   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8
0   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   1  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   2  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   3  0.0  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   5  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   6  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   7  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN
8   8  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN
9   9  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Make columns into rows

```
In [47]: df2.stack().reset_index()
Out[47]: 
    level_0 level_1    0
0         0      ID  0.0
1         1      ID  1.0
2         1      C0  0.0
3         2      ID  2.0
4         2      C0  0.0
..      ...     ...  ...
50        9      C4  4.0
51        9      C5  5.0
52        9      C6  6.0
53        9      C7  7.0
54        9      C8  8.0

[55 rows x 3 columns]

In [48]: df2 = df2.stack().reset_index()
```

rename

```
In [49]: df2.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [50]: df2
Out[50]: 
    A   B    C
0   0  ID  0.0
1   1  ID  1.0
2   1  C0  0.0
3   2  ID  2.0
4   2  C0  0.0
.. ..  ..  ...
50  9  C4  4.0
51  9  C5  5.0
52  9  C6  6.0
53  9  C7  7.0
54  9  C8  8.0

[55 rows x 3 columns]
```

This is tidy data, IOW its normalized and useful to work with.

```
In [51]: df2.to_hdf('test.h5','df',format='table')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You are completely right: I solve this problem in an odd way. The reason why I do this is storage space, which is the reason why I don't do any padding. I tried your solution and it produces a file of size 1.46 Gb whereas my "solution" only requires 401.5 MB. I use for this example df['ID'] = [el for el in np.arange(10000)]. As this is too large of a file for my purposes, I really want to avoid padding. Any idea how this can be done?